# I want to know a generic method for scrolling and clicking on each element of the menu

Tags: java, scroll, menu, click, appium

[image]

I want to scroll through the menu of this and other related application and also want to click on them. So kindly tell a method that can work on all applications in Appium Java

this is my code by far that clicks on menu button of all applications but does not scroll or click :

```
package project;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.touch.TouchActions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.PressesKeyCode;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidKeyCode;

public class firstpro {
    static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setCapability("deviceName", "Samsung Galaxy");
    caps.setCapability("udid", "HFTUN678");
    caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.0");
    caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.olx.pk");
    caps.setCapability("appActivity", 
    "pl.tablica2.activities.ProxyActivity");


        try {
            driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } 
        menus();
    }

    public static void menus() {
       WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10000);
       WebElement Element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("android.view.ViewGroup")));
       driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.ImageButton")).click();
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to shout. Please see [this guide on how to ask questions on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried?

Comment: I apologize if you felt that way :). I tried to take the length of the menu and scroll and click through that but wasn't successful. Can you tell some code that can work for all application?

Comment: There was one more thing all menu bars have "Home" as their first option so can a loop be run to start clicking from home and when it finds home again then stop?

Comment: Please show what you currently have, so we know what to work off of.

Comment: public static void menus() 
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10000);
     WebElement Element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("android.view.ViewGroup")));
        driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.ImageButton")).click(); }

Comment: This is the menu method that clicks on menu button for all applications and i called this in the main method but dont know how to make it click and scroll through menus of all applications

Comment: please put code as an edit to your question

Comment: I have added the code but removed the basics because I struggling while adding the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code, I'm not sure how accurate it is since I still don't know the full node tree structures but it should give you a good idea of some approaches you can take:

```
public static void menus() {
    List<WebElement> scrollViews = driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.ScrollView"));
    Iterator<WebElement> it = scrollViews.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        WebElement scrollView = it.next();
        // make sure this scroll view has the child element "Home"
        List<WebElement> homeElements = scrollView.findElements(By.xpath("*[text() = 'Home' or text() = 'home']"));
        if(homeElements.isEmpty()) {
            // filter out scroll views that don't have a child with the text "Home"
            it.remove();
        } else if (homeElements.size() > 1) {
            // this scroll view has multiple children with the text "Home"
        }
    }

    if(scrollViews.isEmpty()) {
        // TODO error, couldn't find any scroll view containing a child with the text "Home"
    } else if (scrollViews.size() > 1) {
        // TODO error, there are multiple scroll views containing children with the text "Home"
    }

    // the only scroll view that has a child with text "Home"
    // likely the main menu scroll view
    WebElement targetMenuScrollView = scrollViews.get(0);

    // get all the ImageButtons in the menu
    List<WebElement> menuButtons = targetMenuScrollView
            .findElements(By.className("android.widget.ImageButton"));

    // click all the buttons
    for (WebElement button : menuButtons) {
        button.click();
    }
}
```

Comment: its not clicking any of the buttons in the menu although still opening the menu

Comment: I have also added whole of my code, can you kindly look at it again :)

Comment: Please show me the full node tree and specify which nodes you want to be clicked, I'm trusting that the buttons are `android.widget.ImageButton` as you say but is the `menuButtonContainer` getting the right node. You need to make sure that `wait.until(...)` is actually selecting the parent node that contains all the buttons you want clicked. You can run a debugger and put a breakpoint to see what node actually gets selected and see its children.

Comment: wouldn't it vary from application to application because I want a generic method that can scroll through the menu of all native applications and also click

Comment: Since it varies from application to application do you have any good ideas on how to determine the menu node? The class for the menu might not be the same between applications, so you can't select `By.className()`, there's no guarantee that the buttons will be `android.widget.ImageButton`s either. You'll need to look at multiple applications and find some sufficient commonality between them, otherwise there's no way to do this generically.

Comment: So define what "menu" you want to click buttons in, what distinguishes it from any other node that might have buttons in it?  As long as we can get the menu then we could just click everything in it to make sure we got the buttons.

Comment: android.widget.ImageButton is for clicking on the menu button and android.widget.ScrollView has all these elements that i was to click and scroll through

Comment: every application have home as the start element so can we add a loop that starts clicking from home and when it finds home again it stops?

Comment: Edited my answer, hopefully it can help you but unfortunately since I can't see all the full node trees it's kinda hard to come up with something.

Comment: Can you send me an email or something I would send the code over there?